How to add dynamic data to Powerpoint using node
I have a powerpoint file which has multiple slides. Each slide consist of some template & some data. Every slide has same template and i need to insert data into each & every slide manually. Is there any way to automate it using node.

I got one solution:
Algorithm:
1]Save pptx file as svg file
2] Give ids to the dynamic portion and place dynamic content using xml-js npm library:
const { xml2js, js2xml } = require('xml-js');

// Load the SVG file
const svgData = fs.readFileSync('input.svg', 'utf8');

// Parse the SVG data
const svgObject = xml2js(svgData, { compact: false });

console.log(svgObject.elements[0].elements[0].elements, 'svgObject.elements');

// Find the SVG text element with a specific ID
function findElementById(elements, id) {
    for (const element of elements) {
        if (element.attributes && element.attributes.id === id) {
            return element;
        }
        if (element.elements) {
            const foundElement = findElementById(element.elements, id);
            if (foundElement) {
                return foundElement;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// Call the recursive search function to find an element with ID 'skills'
const textElement = findElementById(svgObject.elements, 'skills');

// Modify text content of the found element (if exists)
if (textElement) {
    // Change the text content to 'New Content'
    textElement.elements = [{
        type: 'text',
        text: 'New Content'
    }];
}

if (textElement) {
    console.log('Element with ID "skills" found:', textElement);
} else {
    console.log('Element with ID "skills" not found.');
}


// Convert the modified SVG object back to XML
const outputSVG = js2xml(svgObject, { compact: false, spaces: 2 });

// Save the modified SVG
fs.writeFileSync('output.svg', outputSVG, 'utf8');

console.log('SVG modified and saved successfully!');

3]You will get the modified svg.
4] You can convert it to any file format you need.

There are few libraries via which you can achieve this. One way to achieve this is by using libraries like pptxgenjs or pptxgenjs-client PptxGenJS which provide APIs to create and modify PowerPoint presentations programmatically.

This library doesn't allow to modify existing pptx file..

Is it necessary to do it in node? VBA/COM automation would make this possible and not too complex. Or there are several inexpensive existing add-ins that can merge text and in some cases, other content, from an Excel worksheet into your template PPT/PPTX.  Of course, these would mostly be Windows-only solutions and not recommended for server use.

No..it's not node specific. It can be done by any way...

If VBA add-ins are acceptable and can run on a Windows desktop with PPT installed, have a look at http://pptalchemy.co.uk/Simple_merge.html by John Wilson, or my PPTools Merge, https://pptools.com/merge/
